# how to escape * in a script

Tags: escaping, glob

I am trying to write a bash script with a function that executes the following query:

```bash
query() {
    cmd="mysql -N -B -u $user -p$password -h $host -e \"$q;\"" #2>&1";
    eval $cmd
}
```

with

```bash
q="select * from mydatabase.mytable"
```

Upon calling the query, the `*` character messes everything up and expands to a listing of the current directory.

How can I avoid this? The function should accept any valid SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling globbing with set -f seems to solve the problem:

```
query(){
set -f
cmd="mysql -N -B -u $user -p$password -h $host -e \"$q;\"" #2>&1";
echo $cmd
eval $cmd
set +f
}
```

Is this the best way?